# How to get Laravel api resource based data in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to show user projects list where `user_id` column is match with `auth()->user()->id`.

the problem i have is how to define what function of my resourced route to use.

## Code

`Controller`

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->latest()->take(10)->get();
        return response()->json($projects);
    }

    public function userprojects()
    {
        $projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return $projects;
    }
}
```

`Api route`

```
Route::resource('projects', 'Api\ProjectController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
```

`Vue component`

```
<template>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Your Published Projects <span class="badge badge-info">{{projects.length}}</span></div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
                            {{project.title}} - {{project.user_id}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            projects: []
        }
    },
    created(){
            this.fetchProjects();
        },
        methods:{
            fetchProjects(){
                var self = this;
                axios.get('api/projects')
                    .then(function (resp) {
                        self.projects = resp.data;
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                        alert("Could not load projects");
                });
            },
        },
}
</script>
```

## Question

1. How do I tell my component to not load `index` function but to load
   data from `userprojects` function?

Answer (score 1):

So you could add a new route

```
Route::get('projects-user', 'Api\ProjectController@userprojects')->name('userprojects');
```

In js.

```
axios.get(Router('userprojects').url()).then(response => {
    this.userprojects= response.data;
});
```

Also you could do just this in the controller

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      if(Auth::check()){
        $projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
      }else{
        $projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->latest()->take(10)->get();
      }

        return response()->json($projects);
    }

}
```

Comment: is 2 different things bro, i need my index to load all projects and my other function to show each user projects to them.

Comment: So you could add a new route Route::get('projects-user', 'Api\ProjectController@userprojects')->name('userprojects');

In js.

axios.get(Router('userprojects').url()).then(response => {
                    this.userprojects= response.data;
                });

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new route before the resource route and use it:

```
Route::get('projects/me', 'Api\ProjectController@userprojects', ['except' => ['create', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
Route::resource('projects', 'Api\ProjectController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
```

then on your component:

```
axios.get('api/projects/me')
.then(function (resp) {
    self.projects = resp.data;
})
```

Comment: thanks bro, i did that it will recognize route however it gets error with `id` in `Auth::user()->id` so i tried `Auth::id()` it returns `[]` then i tried hard coded id and it did work, now how should i get my auth user id in api controller? it appears is different with usual controllers where we simply get aut user id by `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: use `Auth::user()->getKey()` instead.

Comment: `Auth::user()->getKey()` resolves the id column of your table based on the value of the `$primaryKey` property inside your model.

Comment: it returns `Call to a member function getKey() on null`

Comment: that means you are not authenticated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177537/discussion-between-julian-paolo-dayag-and-mafortis).